# how to include variables in json urlstring

Tags: iphone, ios, json

How do I replace the values to variables.

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL
 URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food"]];
```

I would like to replace

```
1) -33.867
2) 151
3) 500
4) food
```

with variables in the URLWithString.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float latitude = -33.8670522f;
float longitude = 151.1957362f;
int radius = 500;
NSString* types = @"food";

NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%d&types=%@", latitude, longitude, radius, type];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

I'm not sure if I got the latitude / longitude right or if it has to be vice versa, but anyway, you get the idea! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried something similar on another url with 2 strings and I get an error :Too many arguments on method call expected 1 ,have 3.

Comment: NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?email=%@&pass=%@",name, pass];    this gives me the error.

Comment: You have to specify one formatter per argument you add to your `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create some kind of factory method:

```
- (NSURL *) URLForPlaceForType:(NSString *)typ atLat:(double)lat lng:(double)lng radius:(NSInteger)radius {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%d&types=%@", lat, lng, radius, type];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:path]; 
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar on another url with 2 strings and I get an error :Too many arguments on method call expected 1 ,have 3

Comment: The means that your are passing to many argument to the `stringWithFormat:` method. The have to be an equal number of formatters as there are parameters.

Comment: NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?email=%@&pass=%@",name, pass];           This gives me the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find answer in NSString class reference ?

```
Finding Characters and Substrings
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:
– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:
– rangeOfString:
– rangeOfString:options:
– rangeOfString:options:range:
– rangeOfString:options:range:locale:
– enumerateLinesUsingBlock:
– enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:
```